# VBA Concatenate string with previous string value (previous value changes every few cells)

Tags: arrays, vba, string, uppercase

I am working on building data historical of Financial System.

I need a macro that reads if the cell doesn´t contain uppercase, then concatenates the text of this cell with the previous value that was uppercases.

```
|    FIRST STEP    |
|------------------|
|     |    Name    |
| --- | ---------- |
|  1  |DISPONIBLE: | 
|  2  |Caja        |
|  3  |Bancos      |
|  4  |INVERSIONES:|
|  5  |Temporales  |
|  6  |Largoplazo  |
|  7  |CARTERA:    |
|  8  |Crédito     |
```

```
|     |    LAST STEP         |
|----------------------------|
|     |    Name              |
| --- | -------------------- |
|  1  |DISPONIBLE:           | 
|  2  |disponibleCaja        |
|  3  |disponibleBancos      |
|  4  |INVERSIONES:          |
|  5  |inversionesTemporales |
|  6  |inversionesLargoplazo |
|  7  |CARTERA:              |
|  8  |carteraCrédito        |
```

Comment: Please [check how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and get answers on this site

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim capitalWord As String
Set rng = Range("A1:A8") 'Adjust as needed
For Each cel In rng
    If IsUppercase(cel.Value) Then
        capitalWord = Replace(cel.Value, ":", "")
    Else
        cel.Value = LCase(capitalWord) & WorksheetFunction.Proper(cel.Value)
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
Public Function IsUppercase(AString As String) As Boolean
  IsUppercase = (UCase(AString) = AString)
End Function
```

Basically it checks if the cell is uppercase, and if so, sets that as the `capitalWord`. Otherwise, adds the lowercase of that word to the cell value.